# Is a nearly-fixed background image (scrolls for n pixels, then fixed) possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Finally getting around to designing a site for my personal domain, and I've encountered an issue with the background image I'd like to use.

The image is of a skyline, but flipped such that the buildings come down from the top of the page. Below the inverted skyline there is a gradient from sky colors (in this case green/yellow/orange) to white.

I hope to accomplish a scrolling effect wherein the entire page scrolls initially, until the buildings are ~50% off the page (lets say 75px), at which point the background becomes fixed and only text (ideally both Header and Body) scrolls beyond that.

In effect, the page background becomes the tops of the skyscrapers at the very top of the page, and a majority the sky-white gradient.

My CSS skills are fairly rudimentary and my JQuery skills nonexistent. I'm comfortable hacking things together but don't feel capable of much else beyond that. Unfortunately, the nearest things I've found through GOOG/SO searches have been related to parallax scrolling, which isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is possible. I would use jQuery. You would take a look at the scroll position of the window itself. If scroll position is greater than a certain threshold then you would fix the skyline at its current position. If it is less than thenswitch it back. I think you would need to dynamically assign the fixed position to keep it from looking jerky.

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
console.log($(window).scrollTop());
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
    $(body).css(''); //reposition background image using 'top'
}
else {
     $(body).css(''); //put background image back using 'top'
}
```

});

I can't say whether this will work well or will look herky jerky. But it would be a cool effect. If you get it working post a link to it!